# Unable to run docker container which has CPP code pthread_setschedparam()

Tags: c++, docker, ubuntu-16.04, thread-priority, linux-capabilities

I have a docker container, which has CPP code in it.

```
void SetRealtimeThreadPriority()
{
    sched_param const param{ThreadPriorities::Priority()};
    int result = pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), ThreadPriorities::Policy(), &param);
    printf("SetRealtimeThreadPriority - result checked for assertion %d \n", result);
    assert(result == 0); (void) result;
}
```

when I run the exe which has this code in ubuntu machine it works fine, where **result** printed is **0(zero)**. but when I run it in container, the assert is failing.

I have gone through multiple threads, man pages, docker run documentation and articles and tried running the container with below options, but no luck.

```
docker run -it --rm --cap-add SYS_NICE MyContainer
docker run --cap-add=ALL --privileged MyContainer
docker run --cap-add=ALL MyContainer
docker run -it --rm --userns host --cap-add SYS_NICE MyContainer
```

How can I debug this issue?  Im running docker on wsl ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you verify that the result is EPERM?

Comment: @Botje how can I check the result, I am running the docker in windows machine on wsl terminal im just getting the error as below:
``TimedCallbackManager.cpp:27:  void OSA::SetRealtimeThreadPriority(): Assertion result == 0 failed.`` 

Im running the container as root user

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could insert some code. Perhaps you can tell what is different? For example, `#include <sys/capability.h>`, and link with `... -lcap`, put this:

```
std::cout << cap_to_text(cap_get_proc(), NULL) << std::endl;
```

just before the call to `pthread_setschedparam(2)`. Does it display something different inside and outside the container?